# Bounded double derivative in $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus

Suppose there is a twice continuously differentiable function. 
Suppose, for a real number $M$, $|f''(x)|<M$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, how can we show that $f'(x)$ is bounded in $[0,1]$…

My try:

$|\frac{f'(b)-f'(a)}{b-a}|<M$

$\implies|f'(b)-f'(a)|<M$, since $|b-a|<1$

How can i proceed further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a = 0$ and $b = x \in [0,1]$ be arbitrary. By the reverse triangle inequality you have shown
$$
|f'(x)| - |f'(0)| \leq |f'(x) - f'(0)| < M \implies |f'(x)| < M + |f'(0)|.
$$

Comment: oops, that was simple!